# 'What I have presented is the first steps' or 'What I have presented are the first steps'

Tags: verbs, relative-pronouns, be

Which is correct:

'What I have presented is the first steps'

or

'What I have presented are the first steps'?

The issues is what counts as the subject of the verb: the relative 'What' (= is), or the plural noun 'steps' (=are).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The subject is the relative pronoun "what," but in this case it must take a plural verb to agree with "steps."

**What I have presented are the first steps.**

The same holds if you invert the sentence:

**The first steps are what I have presented.**

To further clarify, the sentence also doesn't make sense at all if "what" is substituted for a singular noun. You wouldn't for example, say, "the book is the first steps" *or* "the book are the first steps." Using "to be" forces the subject and object to agree in number.